# Is there a way to record video of android phone for more than 3 minutes

Tags: android

I know that from Android Kitkat onwards we can use `adb shell screenrecord` to record our mobile operations. But it is limited to 3 minutes. Is there a way to increase this time duration? Can you help me any other methods to do the same things?